# Better way to make/compare date ranges?

Tags: date, sas

I often have data that has a date1 and a date2. Date1 is the date we guess will have the event and date2 an event. I usually need to make 2 dummy variables where I increment date1 forwards a week and backwards then compare with the other 2. However I keep thinking there must be a better way to create a date range and then compare with a second date!

Is there a way to do this in sas? Basically I want to take date1 and date2 and make this dataset and am wondering if I MUST create 2 additional variables (date1-7 days and date1+7days)
Input datset:

```
DATE1         DATE2     



10/23/2014  2/12/2015     


2/12/2015   2/10/2015
```

Current output:

DATE1_wk_before         Date1_wk_after     Date2     In_range_indicator

```
10/16/2014               10/30/2014       2/12/2015       0 


2/05/2015                 2/19/2015       2/10/2015       1
```

Where In_range_indicator = 1 if date is in the range and 0 if not in the range

I want to know if I can do it just where I do something like
In_range_indicator= 1 where Date2 is in range(week before date1 , week after date1) without creating 2 extra sets of data. It seems a waste of time.

I am LITERALLY adding 7 days and subtracting 7 days before and after and it seems a bad way to do this.

Comment: You don't provide enough information for what you're doing here - this doesn't really make sense.  Please provide example initial datasets, then what you're trying to determine, and the final desired dataset, plus the code you now use to get there.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to just want to set the value of a variable based on a condition. No need to get too clever with it, just `if` and `else` in your data step:

```
if date2 ge date1-7 and date2 le date1+7 then ind=1;
else ind=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @DWal, simple if and else statement can help. You can also use IFN function.

```
data mydates;
infile datalines missover;
input (date1-date2) (:mmddyy10.);
In_range_indicator=ifn( date1-7 <= date2 <= date1+7 , 1,0);
format date1-date2 yymmdd10.;
datalines4;
10/23/2014 2/12/2015
2/12/2015 2/10/2015
;;;;
run;
proc print data=mydates;run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if abs(date2-date1)<7 then ind=1; else ind=0;
```